# Resizing a cropped image using jQuery and no server side code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a bit of jquery to search Flickr, produce a set of thumbnails, select a thumbnail, load the fullsize image and then crop the image by setting it as the background image of a DIV. An example of the final genrated DIV containing an image is below:

```
<div class="imgwrapper2" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5094/5425332847_2c4ab1a53a.jpg&quot;); width: 257px; height: 271px; background-position: -69px -77px;">
  &nbsp;
</div>
```

I'd now like to look at resizing the image, well resizing the DIV which contains the background image and stretching the background image.

Is this possible using the above HTML and jQuery? If so can anyone suggest any jQuery plugins that might help?

If you dont think this is possible using the above output, might it be easier if the div wraps an IMG tag with overflow set to invisible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should start thinking about a `<canvas>` solution, like [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/). If you really can't tear yourself away from the jQuery kool-aid, you can [use it as a plugin](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/#jquery).

[Cropping example](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/crop/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the CSS tag background-size

```
<div style="background : url(purple.gif) no-repeat; background-size: 100%;">
```

http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm